# Push data to Firebase via polymerfire/firebase-query element

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, polymer, polymerfire

I'm a little stuck trying to push data on demand to a Firebase database using the polymerfire polymer element. I have a data binding inside a DOM element and it works flawlessly for registers that already exists. My real question is how to create new registers with unique id?

```
//firebase query for a specific path and a data binding
<firebase-query
   id="query"
   app-name="testApp"
   path="/[[uid]]/messages"
   data="{{data}}">
</firebase-query>

//dom repeat for each item inside the data binding
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
   <div class="card">
      <p>[[item.text]]</p>
   </div>
</template>
```

If I modify the template to have an iron-input and a 2 way data binding, this update the register at ease and no problem in Firebase.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
   <div class="card">
      <input is="iron-input" bind-value="{{item.text}}">
   </div>
</template>
```

The real tricky part is how to push a new object (message) to Firebase with a unique id, something like `"lasdjlkadj1978kld"`?

```
//firebase estructure
{
   "uid" : {
      "messages" : {
         "message1" : {
            "message" : "some text",
            "timestamp" : "some date"
         },
         "message2" : {
            "message" : "some text",
            "timestamp" : "some date"
         }
         ...
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

I have tried updating the "data" object via JS but its only modified locally...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly.

> How to create new registers with unique id?

You can use `firebase-document` that provide [`save`](https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/blob/master/firebase-document.html#L82) method that take 2 arguments parentPath and key (just leave the key).

```
<firebase-document id='document'
  data='{{data}}'>
</firebase-document>

<script>
  Polymer({
    saveMessage: function () {
      // path = /<uid>/messages in your case
      this.$.document.save(path).then(function () {
        // after document saved, path will be changed to the new ref
        // any change of data will sent back up and stored
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

> I had tried updating the "data" object via js but its only modified
>   locally...

How you update the `data`, Did you use [`this.set`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-set)?

Comment: im not sure how to use the firebase-document element, the documentation doesn't give much to work with, can you share an example?

Comment: I think this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/polymer-firebase-pwa/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0) is a good one to start (and see at their [behavior](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/note-app/blob/master/common/note-app/na-behavior.html)). I already update my answer hope that help.

Comment: Awesome!!! `this.$.document.save(path).then` works just as expected.... thanks...